# Volley Crashing in onResponse When Creating View

Tags: android, request, android-volley

This will be brief because I have no clue what the problem is. In my onResponse of a Volley Request I'm creating a TextView. In doing so the application crashes. I can't understand the stack trace because it seems to be 90% assembly (and my assembly knowledge consists of 1s and 0s). Here's a link to the stack (It's about 50000 characters and I have no clue what is relevant in it...): https://justpaste.it/16l9m

And here's the onResponse:

```
int i = 0;
            GridLayout.Spec r = GridLayout.spec(0, 1);
            GridLayout.Spec c1 = GridLayout.spec(0, 1);
            GridLayout.LayoutParams f1 = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(r, c1);
            f1.rightMargin = 250;
            GridLayout.Spec c2 = GridLayout.spec(1, 1);
            GridLayout.LayoutParams l1 = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(r, c2);
            l1.rightMargin = 25;
            GridLayout.Spec c3 = GridLayout.spec(2, 1);
            GridLayout.LayoutParams p1 = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(r, c3);
            p1.rightMargin = 25;
            GridLayout.Spec c4 = GridLayout.spec(3, 1);
            GridLayout.LayoutParams co = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(r, c4);
            co.rightMargin = 25;
            GridLayout.Spec c5 = GridLayout.spec(4,1);
            GridLayout.LayoutParams d1 = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(r, c5);
            TextView firstT = new TextView(context);
            firstT.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 13);
            firstT.setText("Product");
            grid.addView(firstT, f1);
            TextView lastT = new TextView(context);
            lastT.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 13);
            lastT.setText("Quantity");
            grid.addView(lastT, l1);
            TextView purchasesT = new TextView(context);
            purchasesT.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 13);
            purchasesT.setText("Price");
            grid.addView(purchasesT, p1);
            TextView creditsT = new TextView(context);
            creditsT.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 13);
            creditsT.setText("Credits");
            grid.addView(creditsT, co);
            /*TextView dateT = new TextView(context);
            creditsT.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 13);
            creditsT.setText("Date");
            grid.addView(dateT, d1);
            */
            grid.refreshDrawableState();
            try {
                while (response.has(String.valueOf(i))) {
                    GridLayout.Spec row = GridLayout.spec(i + 1, 1);
                    GridLayout.Spec col1 = GridLayout.spec(0, 1);
                    GridLayout.LayoutParams f = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(row, col1);
                    GridLayout.Spec col2 = GridLayout.spec(1, 1);
                    GridLayout.LayoutParams l = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(row, col2);
                    GridLayout.Spec col3 = GridLayout.spec(2, 1);
                    GridLayout.LayoutParams p = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(row, col3);
                    GridLayout.Spec col4 = GridLayout.spec(3, 1);
                    GridLayout.LayoutParams c = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(row, col4);
                    GridLayout.Spec col5 = GridLayout.spec(4, 1);
                    GridLayout.LayoutParams d = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(row, col5);
                    TextView first = new TextView(context);
                    first.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 13);
                    first.setText(response.getJSONObject(String.valueOf(i)).getString("Product"));
                    grid.addView(first, f);
                    TextView last = new TextView(context);
                    last.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 13);
                    last.setText(response.getJSONObject(String.valueOf(i)).getString("Quantity"));
                    grid.addView(last, l);
                    TextView purchases = new TextView(context);
                    purchases.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 13);
                    purchases.setText(response.getJSONObject(String.valueOf(i)).get("Price").toString());
                    grid.addView(purchases, p);
                    TextView credits = new TextView(context);
                    credits.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 13);
                    credits.setText(response.getJSONObject(String.valueOf(i)).get("Credits").toString());
                    grid.addView(credits, c);
                    /*TextView date = new TextView(context);
                    credits.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 13);
                    credits.setText(response.getJSONObject(String.valueOf(i++)).get("Date").toString());
                    grid.addView(date, d);
                    */
                    grid.refreshDrawableState();
                }
                pd.cancel();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

It doesn't give the error at the same TextView every time but it's always on the line where I instantiate one the first ones. Lastly, please try not to cringe at the horrible variable names.. I need to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

I mistakenly commented out the section of code containing i++... The while loop was simply never exiting.